# Are all integer fractions rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Any repeating decimal can be written as a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. But is the reverse true. Will any fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers produce a quotient with a repeating decimal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Fractions_with_prime_denominators

Comment: It's a lot more common to define "rational number" to mean "number which is a **ratio** of two integers" than "number which has a repeating decimal expansion" (though these turn out to be equivalent). So you might want to retitle your question -- under that definition, your title is trivial.

Comment: Yes (assuming that $b \ne 0$), if you consider any rational number a repeating decimal (for example, $0.7$ is a terminating decimal, but it can be rewritten as the repeating decimal $0.6999...$).

Answer (score 5):

This question is confused.  The **DEFINITION** of "rational number" is a number that is a quotient of two integers.

It can be shown that every repeating decimal is rational and every rational number is a repeating decimal.  But: DO NOT think that "repeating (or terminating) decimal" is the *definition* of rational number.  No mathematician does that.

The answer is "yes" because of the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  Say, for example you divide $5$ by $82$:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
& & 0 & . & 6 & 0 & 9 & 7 & 5 &   \\[10pt]
82 & ) & 5 & . & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   &   & 4 &   & 9 & 2 \\  \\
   &   &   &   &   & 8 & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   &   & 0 \\  \\
   &   &   &   &   & 8 & 0 & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   & 7 & 3 & 8 \\  \\
   &   &   &   &   &   & 6 & 2 & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   &   & 5 & 7 & 4 \\  \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 4 & 6 & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 4 & 1 & 0 \\  \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 5 & 0 & 0 & \longleftarrow\text{ return to starting point}\\
\end{array}
$$
(We started by asking how many times $82$ goes into $500$ and we said $6$.  Now we are *again* faced with the question of how many times $82$ goes into $500$, and the answer is *still* $6$.)

How do you know that you will eventually return to the starting point, and therefore start repeating?  The answer is: the pigeonhole principle.  Thare are only 82 possible remainders: $0,1,2,3,\ldots, 81$.  If you ever get $0$, the decimal expansion *terminates*.  But if you never get $0$, you can't go more than $81$ steps without getting a remainder that you've seen before, since after $81$ steps you've used them all up.

Comment: Don't be so harsh. To a layman, it's much easier to explain a rational number as having a repeating or terminating decimal expansion.

Comment: @JavierBadia : I don't see why that's easier to explain.

Comment: Maybe easier isn't the best word, but I think people are usually more familiar with decimals than with fractions. Anyway, my point is that I think your first sentence could be worded a bit more nicely.

Comment: I think your insistence on the "definition" of a rational number being the quotient of two integers is silly.  Obviously, since we have just shown equivalence, you could define a rational number as **either** the quotient of two integers **or** a repeating decimal and it would not make **any difference** to mathematics.

Comment: @Goos : We haven't shown here that they are equivalent, but we've shown that the implication goes in one direction.  BUT "quotient of two integers" is to the point; "repeating or terminating decimal" is not.  If we defined it as "repeating or terminating decimal" then we would have to wonder what's so important about base 10 as opposed to other bases, that it should be the one used in the definition.  We'd have to wonder why "repeating or terminating" is worth a concept rather than maybe one for repeating and one for terminating. And.....

Comment: . . . . the notion of "repeating or terminating decimal" does not arise naturally in foundational questions faced when one starts geometry without the concept of real numbers, and one wonders about commensurability of the diagonal and side of a square.  The notion of repeating or terminating decimal does not motivate the concept in the way in which the notion of a quotient of two integers does.  Just think of the problem of defining the field of quotients of an integral domain.  Would you want to do that by thinking about repeating or terminating decimals?

Comment: . . . . or the notion of convolution quotients (really a special case of that last problem).  Repeating or terminating decimals??

Comment: Well, you're right that it's a *better definition* as in it's more practical.  But it's still equivalent, and *logically*, there is no difference between the two.  Also the base 10 thing is really irrelevant because the proof obviously generalizes to any base.  But I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  Every rational number has a repeating decimal expansion.

It's an easy exercise to prove this (hint: consider trailing 9s as above).

Comment: This doesn't do it.  You need the pigeonhole principle. Trailing $9$s don't get you anywhere that you didn't ALREADY get by thinking about trailing $0$s.